# VS2015 use existing cordova installation?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I have a globally installed Cordova on my machine and want to give it a try to visual studio 2015. But it wants to install its own Cordova package. Is it possible to use the existing Cordova install instead?

Comment: I think with VS you can only use VS Tools for Apache Cordova

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. I gonna keep this question opened a bit longer see if anyone has a workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the option to **Use Globally Installed Cordova Version** in your proyect, it will use it instead of its own.